# Time taken for individual transformations in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to come up with a way to measure the time taken by individual transformations in spark. I am using the following code for experimenting for my POC.

```
        StructType newSchema=df.schema().add("CONCAT",DataTypes.StringType);
        LongAccumulator longAccumulator=sparkSession.sparkContext().longAccumulator();

        /* Map partition transformation */

        long start=System.currentTimeMillis();

        df=df.mapPartitions(new MapPartitionsFunction<Row, Row>() {
            long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            @Override
            public Iterator<Row> call(Iterator<Row> it) throws Exception {
                //Some logic
                long endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                longAccumulator.add(endTime-startTime);
                //Rest of the logic
            }
        },RowEncoder.apply(newSchema));

//        df=df.cache();
//        count=df.count();
        long end=System.currentTimeMillis();

        /* withColumn transformation */

        start=System.currentTimeMillis();
        df=df.withColumn("new_col", functions.lit(1));
//        df=df.cache();
//        count=df.count();
        end=System.currentTimeMillis();

        count=df.count();
        df.show();
        System.out.println("Map partition time is "+longAccumulator.value()/df.rdd().getNumPartitions());
```

So, I want to know how much time does the individual transforms like mapPartition and withColumn takes. We were earlier thinking of using cache/persist and then count but on bigger datasets, it's having perfomance issues, since we would have these transformations a lot and can't afford count and cache for all. The earlier approach is commented inside code.

I have been able to calculate time for mapPartition(using accumulator to sum everything and divide by number of partitions) but I am not able to find one for with_column. Can someone suggest something? I am not able to find any online resource for it. If someone has better approach for map partition, please suggest that also.